# What are useful situations to use the 'Sprint Slide' skill in?

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm not exactly sure what the 'Sprint Slide' skill is useful for (compared to simply crouching).

So, what are useful situations to use the 'Sprint Slide' skill in? Can it improve stealth approaches? Any actions with unique results that can be done through it?

[image: 'Sprint Slide' skill]

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can sometimes be useful to quickly pass under an obstacle which otherwise requires crouching, like a low and narrow bridge when you run in a creek bed or a tree log laying over a path.

Just remember that after the slide, your character is in the crouched state, so in order to not lose the valuable milliseconds you just gained, immediately press sprint again to get back into the sprint state.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use it for two things:

1. **Getting to cover fast**
2. **Extending my sprint a little longer** - I try to time it right to hit the sprint slide at the end of my sprint (when he cannot sprint anymore and has to catch his breath)

Other than that - Kotekzot is correct that you need it to unlock more skills.

Comment: How long do you have to run before you're out of breath? I don't think I've ever had it happen (or noticed it happen, anyway).

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no stamina bar and you are always able to sprint.

Answer (score 2):

Sprint slide is mainly useful for 2 purposes:

1. Looking cool.
2. Unlocking actually useful skills.

Comment: "*Looking cool.*" Wait a tick… That's not useful! =)

Comment: @galacticninja It is if it makes the enemies go: Whoa! Look at that cool dude, better not mess with him.

Comment: @Lyrion "*Whoa! Look at that cool dude, better not mess with him.*" Except for the fact that every enemy in Far Cry 3 will shoot/attack you on sight, regardless of the 'cool' actions that you do. =)

Comment: 1. coolness won't have any effect on bots, maybe on MP. 2. pretty obvious.

Comment: +1 If you have no use for "looking cool," then I don't know what to tell you. It really is the single greatest reason to use the Sprint Slide.

Answer (score 1):

I use the sprint slide all the time for moving from cover to cover while on a stealth approach with patrolling guards.  If the guard looks away for a moment, I can dash forward and then begin a slide that takes me back into cover on the other side.